# Creating fake Request

Tags: symfony, twig

I've got a command in Sf2 with such code:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

...

$container = $this->getContainer();

$container->enterScope('request');
$container->set('request', new Request(), 'request');

$context = $container->get('router')->getContext();
$context->setHost($container->getParameter('website_host'));
$context->setScheme($container->getParameter('website_scheme'));
$context->setBaseUrl($container->getParameter('website_path'));
var_dump($context->getBaseUrl());
```

This is what I do in the twig template:

```
{{ render(controller('X:Y:emailMenu')) }}
```

And I get this annoying error:

```
Rendering a fragment can only be done when handling a Request.
```

I already tried `composer update`and:

```
php vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bund
le/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php
```

But I still get the error message. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution worked for me in SF 2.4:

```
...
$r = new Request();
$r->setLocale('fr');
$container->set('request', $r, 'request');
$container->get('request_stack')->push($r);
```

So had to add this line to use request_stack :

**$container->get('request_stack')->push($r);**

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Thanks very much.  This was exactly what I was looking for and it worked perfectly.